# Try to add maven project to tomcat server to run but can't do so

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

In SpringToolSuit IDE, I have created a maven project (it has Spring webmvc dependency). I created this project through File --> New--> Maven project.

The pom.xml has those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also configured a tomcat server on the IDE. When I try to add my maven project to tomcat to run, I always get message **"There are no resources that can be added or removed from server"**.

I did some research, people normally suggest go to Properties--> Project facet and check the "Dynamic Web Module" to resolve this issue. But for me there is no such option:

[image]

How to get rid of this issue & have my project running on tomcat server?

I am using Spring Tool Suite 4:

Version: 4.0.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201809220817

Comment: Can you please share your java project in github?

Comment: the main question here is which version of the Spring Tool Suite you are using? If you have, for example, Spring Tool Suite 4 for Eclipse prior to version 4.2.2, you are probably missing a few m2e extensions to make the above described use case - and updating an existing STS4 install to 4.2.2 doesn't help here since it doesn't install the additional features that are necessary for this. In that case, I recommend to either download a fresh STS 4.2.2 distribution and go from there or install the m2e-wtp extension from the main Eclipse update site into your existing install. That should help.